# RAM allocation on board with different number of slots per CPU

Tags: memory

Recently I stumbled upon a board which apparently has 6 RAM Slots on one CPU and only 3 for the other

Considering it's always said to populate both CPUs equally, there are a few questions:

1) why would someone do this? I mean one would then as per my assumption either populate both CPUs with 3 RAM sticks each leaving the other 3 empty (which they just could have ommitted), or only use CPU 1 and put in 6 RAM Sticks there (then one could as well just use a single socket board)

2) what would be decent RAM configurations on such a board?

Comment: Does this board have any identifying information?

Comment: it has written S5520HC on it but (but rather seems to be an S5500HCV according to the manual, which is weird) I wanted to ask this more as a general question in case there are other boards and people with the same problem

Comment: There's a manual too? Please be specific as to what this board is, as there might be no "general" answer.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520hc/sb/e39527008_s5520hc_s5500hcv_service_guide.pdf
that's the manual which is about 3 boards at once, but the kicker is that the board has written "S5520HC" written on it but that board doesnt have the RAM slot problem but according to the manual only the S5500HCV has which is crazy. Intel told me on twitter that the writing on the board apparently is only the family which is fairly bonkers but well...

Comment: OK, that's a truly bizarre layout. It looks like the S5500HCV in the manual. Since it's a 10 year old board, I am not sure you will get a satisfying answer, though.

Comment: it is bizzare which is why I am asking in the first place, after all as said I always heard that both CPUs should get the same RAM allocation

Answer (score 0):

The manual says:

Intel® Server Board S5500HCV

o Nine DIMM slots.

o Two DIMM slots on each channel of processor socket 1.

o One DIMM slot on each channel of processor socket 2.

While this apparently makes no sense, it actually means that each CPU socket has the same number of channels, meaning that for socket 1 you can use 2 smaller size (N GB) DIMMs and for socket 2 one larger size (Nx2 GB) DIMM and get the same amount of RAM.

Note: in the case on socket 1 what that actually means is that you need to have DIMM pairs in order to use those channels.

A possible logic for this is upgrading in time.

Let's say you got on the board initially 6x1GB DIMMs. In time, you want to upgrade and add the other CPU and RAM for it. But in time, larger memory modules are manufactured. So by the time you want to upgrade, 2GB DIMMs will be largely available and you could put 3x2GB DIMMs for the second CPUs socket.

This can also be related to how DIMMs are internally constructed (single sided vs double sided). In that case, smaller single sided DIMMs will be best used on socket 1 while double sided larger ones on the second one.

Comment: sounds generally logical but it also says "Mixing memory type, size, speed, and/or rank on this platform has not been validated and is not supported", which basically negates this idea.

Comment: That's not what it refers to. You can use different sizes per channel on any MB ever invented.

Comment: okay? well okay lol. well one never stops learning